# how to solve OnClickListner() ---cannot resolve mathod 'OnClickListner()'.?

Tags: android, error-handling

I wanna solve this ***Android*** studio problem for my project further it just stopped working and shows such error that

> R.id.buttonClick R is undefined symbol or Cannot resolve this Symbol.

Comment: need more info. Check for any errors in you reources or project. clean and build

Comment: I dont get such build error but i get error in mainactivity.java class.It just happens before two days otherwise it would run smoother in my device

Comment: it shows error in same mathod like **OnClickListner()**- which is already defined in android earlier and with the same program i got error that-**Can not resolve some Symbol**

Comment: pls check the Related section at te right handle side of this page.

Comment: Thanks a Lot I got it. Please rate my Question.

Comment: Try posting the code that shows the error